# Question of The Day

Tags: feature-request, questions

This would be an interesting feature, how about a **Question Of The Day** leaderboard?

So right now Users leaderboard is week/month/year.. etc.  The **Questions/Votes** tab could use a similar subcategorization (Day, Week (last 7 days), Month (last 30 days), All Time)

The **Views** tab could be organized this way as well.

Right now its stuck to All Time, which is useful, but very static